# How to safely delete a struct

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, heap-memory

I have defined this struct :

```
typedef struct ethernet_header
{
    UCHAR m_dest[6];
    UCHAR m_source[6];
    USHORT m_type;
}   ETHER_HDR;
```

Then I used it in a function like this :

```
void SniffPacket(u_char* p_buffer, int p_size)
{
    //Ethernet header
    ETHER_HDR *l_ethHeader = (ETHER_HDR *)p_uffer;

    //Do Something 
    //How to safely delete l_ethHeader;
}
```

Now I want to delete `l_ethHeader` before the function leaves. How to safely do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have essentially done is told the compiler to treat the `p_buffer` pointer value as though it was a pointer to your struct, but in doing so *no extra memory was allocated*.  The same memory is being looked at - just with a different interpretation.

If you wish to keep the header you could do either this:

```
ETHER_HDR l_ethHeader = *(ETHER_HDR *)p_uffer;
```

which would allocate a header struct on the stack that would automatically be destroyed as it went out of scope.

Or this:

```
ETHER_HDR* l_ethHeader = new ETHER_HDR( *(ETHER_HDR *)p_uffer );
```

Which would allocate a struct on the heap which *would* need deleting later.

All else being equal you should opt for option 1, 'always favour the stack'.

Comment: what if l_ethHeader was declared out of the function (a global variable)?

Comment: Declaring it which way?  Yours?  One of mine?  Although to be frank it doesn't change much: using your way means no extra memory was allocated so no delete required, using my first way it will go out of scope and be destroyed when the program closes so no delete required, my second way you would at some point need to delete it to avoid a memory leak.

Answer (score 7):

You don't!

You only `delete` what you `new` -- and there is no `new` here.

Comment: ok, is it allocated from heap or from stack? and is the memory freed when the function ends?

Comment: @ManoubiJonson:  How can I tell how this memory is allocated?  You haven't shown that code.  You're just casting a pointer that was passed in to the function.  The memory pointed to by `p_buffer` will not be freed when the function ends -- but there is no indication here that it should be.

Comment: Indeed the passed in buffer could be an array on the stack and not need explicitly deleting at all.  In fact if it's being used just to receive a header of known length, it probably *should* be on the stack !  :-)

Answer (score 3):

Most coding style guide suggest that whoever allocate the memory is also responsible for deallocating it.

Your dealloocation depends on how it was allocated -- your code does not allocate anything, so I would not expect any deallocations either, but the function which called your function may need to deallocate.

If it was allocated using malloc -- then you simply free.

If your struct was allocated using "new" then you must use "delete" and make sure that your pointer is of the same type or a derived type (inheritance) as deconstructors may not fire correctly otherwise.

In your case the struct is a plain-old-data-type so it is impossible to say if it was allocated using malloc, new or if it is a stack variable -- the latter needs no deallocation at all as the return will take care of that.

Comment: Note that you must use the same *form* of `delete` that you used for `new`.  ie, if you used `new[]`, you must use `delete[]`.  If you used `new`, you must use `delete`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your `p_buffer` is already allocated when you enter `SniffPacket`, you do not deallocate it in the function - as your function appears to be designed to "sniff", not to manage memory.

If it is not allocated (e.g. `p_buffer` is `NULL` or uninitialized) when you enter `SniffPacket`, then you are invoking undefined behavior in your cast, so anything you do after that is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

It depends,

If you have allocated the memory using the **new** then you must use **delete** or **delete[]** (if it is an array), if you have allocated the memory using the **malloc** function then you must use **free**.

Regards